# Adding a margin/padding to bottom and 100% height of vertical line menubar.

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on this page and there are some things i can't figure out.

First: I would like a padding/margin at the bottom of my container. I tried adding it in the CSS but i think I'm missing something somewhere?

Second: I want the border of the .menubar to be 100% of the height.

Hope someone can help me out. Thank you.

Here's my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtBsq/1/

and the code itself

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Portfolio Kevin Schouten</title>
<link href="online portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body id="home_page">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="menubar">
        <div id="logo" class="box">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/logo.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="logo kevin schouten"> </a>  
        </div>
            <div id="about" class="box">
            <a href="about.html"><img src="Images/about.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="about Kevin Schouten"> 
            </a> </div>
            <div id="design" class="box">
            <a href="design.html"><img src="Images/design.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Design Kevin Schouten"> 
            </a> </div>
            <div id="drawings" class="box">
            <a href="drawings.html"><img src="Images/drawings.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Drawings Kevin 
Schouten"> </a> </div>
            <div id="video" class="box">
            <a href="video.html"><img src="Images/Video.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Video's Kevin Schouten"> 
            </a> </div>
            <div id="digital" class="box">
            <a href="digital.html"><img src="Images/digital.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Digital Kevin 
            Schouten"> </a> </div>
            <div id="contact">
                <div id="facebook" class="box">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/kevin.schouten" target="new"><img src="Images/facebook.png" width=
                "100%" height="100%" alt="facebook Kevin Schouten"> </a> </div>
                <div id="email" class="box">
                <a href="mailto: kevinschouten123@gmail.com"><img src="Images/email.png" width="100%" height="100%" 
                alt="Email Kevin Schouten"> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="icoon">
            <img src="Images/signature.png" width="70%" height="180px" alt="signature Kevin Schouten" id="signature">                       
            </div>
          </div>
    <div class="content" id="content"> 
        <div id=info>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(Images/achtergrond.jpg);
    background-size: auto;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;

}

.menubar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(36,36,36,0.5);
}

.content{
    float: right;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 85%;
}
.box {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(36,36,36,0.5)
}

.box:hover{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}

#logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;   
}

#about {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

#design {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

#drawings {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
#video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
#digital {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
#contact {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
#facebook {
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    width: 49.5%;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(36,36,36,0.5);
}
#email {
    height: 60px;
    width: 49.5%;
    float: right;

}
#icoon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 215px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(36,36,36,0.5);
}

#home_page #logo{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}
#about_page #about{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}
#design_page #design{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}
#drawings_page #drawings{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}
#video_page #video{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}
#digital_page #digital{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}

#info {
    float: left;
    height: 700px;
    width: 80%;
    min-width:600px;
    left: 10%;
    background-color: rgba(26,26,26,1);
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#signature {
    float: left;
    left: 15%;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like a padding/margin at the bottom of my container. I tried adding it in the CSS but i think I'm missing something somewhere?

You are missing that floated elements don’t normally affect the height of their parent element – and therefor your container is not as high as you think (you could have found that out easily yourself in your browser’s developer tools!), so you see no effect of any bottom padding.

One method to get floated elements “included” is `overflow:hidden` in the parent element. Set that (and make the height a min-height), and it works:

```
.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZtBsq/2/

(And for the border, please research “faux columns” or “equal height columns”.)